# My header text won't move in correlation to the window size

Tags: html, css

In my portfolio, I want to create a header that would be compatible with every screen size, which would mean the text would fit on the screen regardless of what size it is and one way I can test this is by using a responsive screen in the inspect element. The problem I have though is that the text in my header is static whenever I resize it, meaning that it would hide away from the screen when I shorten it

[image]

I tried to fix it by adding `position: absolute;`  to my header css and eventually every single one of the links but that didn't work. I  tried `position: fixed;` and even `display: flex` but that didn't work as well so I don't know what to do.

```css
li a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.about {
  position: absolute;
  padding-left: 10vh;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding-right: auto;
}
.skills {
  position: absolute;
  padding-left: 60vh;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding-right: auto;
}
.projects {
  position: absolute;
  padding-left: 100vh;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding-right: auto;
}
.contacts {
  position: absolute;
  padding-left: 150vh;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding-right: auto;
}
.title {
  margin-bottom: 6vh;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

header {
  padding-bottom: 8px;
  padding-top: 9px;
}
```

```html
<header>  
        <ul className="title">
           <li className="about"><a href="#">ABOUT ME</a></li>
           <li className="skills"><a href="#">SKILLS</a></li>
           <li className="projects"><a href="#">PROJECTS</a></li>
           <li className="contacts"><a href="#">CONTACTS</a></li>
        </ul>
</header>
```

Bonus Question:

I also have trouble removing that bullet point beside the **ABOUT ME** link so any suggestions on how to fix it would appreciate me as well

Comment: Absolute positioning is a **very** poor method of laying out webpages. It is extremely inflexible and there are much better and more responsive options. Check out [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Comment: Yeah, I'd be using flexbox here.

Comment: @isherwood  The flexboxes didn't work for me as well

Comment: The code in given snippet doesn't recreate what's shown in the image

Comment: Also ask one specific question per post, multiple questions per post will end up with answers like the current one that doesn't solve the problem

Comment: @Sean Reilly has the correct answer for you below. Also wanted to point out that what you're doing with padding is misguided. You are trying to set horizontal padding based on the _height_ of a user's screen. With flexbox you won't need this padding, but in the future you'll make it easier on yourself if you use VW (viewport width) for left/right alignment.

Answer (score 1):

Never use absolute positioning to position all your elements especially when it's a normal layout such as on top of each other or next to each other, like yours.

A better layout can be achieved very easily.

```css
.header{
    padding: 1rem 0;
}

ul{
    list-style:none;
}

li a {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.title{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
```

```html
<header>  
    <ul class="title">
       <li><a href="#">ABOUT ME</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">SKILLS</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">PROJECTS</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">CONTACTS</a></li>
    </ul>
</header>
```

Instead of styling all elements individually, you should try and find groups and style them together. So instead of styling each `li`, you should style the whole `ul`, for example.

Comment: I don't know why, but for me, the words are just grouped to the left and not spaced evenly like in the snippet

Comment: Ok, I solved it by adding a width to the .title but the text still won't adjust to the screen

Comment: Make sure you remove all other styles related to the header and ul and then it should work like the snippet

Answer (score 0):

For bullet point beside the ABOUT ME use:

```
li{
    list-style:none
}
```

And for compatible with every screen size you can use **media queries**

Comment: Thank you for the ABOUT ME problem, your answer helped me with it. As for the compatible with every screen size, the media queries also help but I want the texts to automatically adjust to the screen sizes. The reason is because I managed to do it in my previous projects but this one just doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

please follow this code

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-iBBXm8fW90+nuLcSKlbmrPcLa0OT92xO1BIsZ+ywDWZCvqsWgccV3gFoRBv0z+8dLJgyAHIhR35VZc2oM/gI1w==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
```

```js
let toggle = document.getElementById("toggle"); toggle.addEventListener("click", () => { let nav_p = document.getElementById("nav_p"); nav_p.classList.toggle("nav_active"); });
```

```css
*{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    body{
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }
    
    .container {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 0 15px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    
    @media(min-width: 576px) {
        .container {
            max-width: 540px;
        }
    }
    
    @media(min-width: 768px) {
        .container {
            max-width: 720px;
        }
    }
    
    @media(min-width: 992px) {
        .container {
            max-width: 960px;
        }
    }
    
    @media(min-width: 1200px) {
        .container {
            max-width: 1152px;
        }
    }
    
    li{
        list-style: none;
    }
    
    a{
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    /* all css code  */
    
    /* nav phone  */
    
    .nav-p{
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: -1000px;
        width: 35%;
        height: 665px;
        /*background: #a29bfe;
        */background: #2c2c54;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        padding-top: 50px;
        transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
        -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
        -o-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    }
    
    .nav_active{
        left: 0 !important;
    }
    
    .logo-p{
        margin-bottom: 100px;
    }
    
    .nav-links-p li{
        padding: 10px;
        transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
        -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
        -o-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    }
    
    .nav-links-p li:hover{
        border-bottom: 1px solid white;
    }
    
    .nav-links-p li a{
        color: white;
        
    }
    
    /* nav phone end */
    
    
    header{
        padding: 10px 0;
        /* background: #303335; */
        background: #40407a;
        position: relative;
    }
    
    .nav-d{
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
    }
    
    #logo{
        width: 100px;
    }
    
    #logo img{
        width: 100%;
    }
    
    .nav-links{
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
    }
    
    .nav-links li:not(:last-child){
        margin-right: 25px;
    }
    
    
    .nav-links li a{
        color: white;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    
    #toggle{
        align-items: center;
        display: none;
    }
    
    #toggle i{
        font-size: 28px;
        color: white;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    /* all responsive code  */
    
    @media(max-width: 992px){
        .nav-links{
            display: none;
        }
        #toggle{
            display: flex;
        }
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-iBBXm8fW90+nuLcSKlbmrPcLa0OT92xO1BIsZ+ywDWZCvqsWgccV3gFoRBv0z+8dLJgyAHIhR35VZc2oM/gI1w==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
</head>
<body>

    <header>  
        <div class="container">
           <nav id="nav_p" class="nav-p">
               <div id="logo" class="logo-p">
                   <img src="https://habrastorage.org/getpro/habr/comment_images/8cf/deb/d58/8cfdebd58675bc96050d98524f8d051b.png" alt="logo">
                </div>
               <ul class="nav-links-p">
                   <li><a href="#">ABOUT ME</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">SKILLS</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">PROJECTS</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">CONTACTS</a></li>
                </ul>
           </nav>
           <nav class="nav-d">
               <div id="logo">
                  <img src="https://habrastorage.org/getpro/habr/comment_images/8cf/deb/d58/8cfdebd58675bc96050d98524f8d051b.png" alt="logo">
               </div>
               <ul class="nav-links">
                  <li><a href="#">ABOUT ME</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">SKILLS</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">PROJECTS</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">CONTACTS</a></li>
               </ul>
               <div id="toggle">
                   <i class="fas fa-bars "></i>
               </div>
           </nav>
        </div>
   </header>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please add some comments about your code and how does it answers the question.

Comment: please check now

Answer (score -1):

****Try this****

```css
 a{
 color: black;
  text-decoration: none;


.about {
 color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: absolute;
  padding-left: 10vh;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding-right: auto;
}
.skills {
  position: absolute;
  padding-left: 60vh;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding-right: auto;
}
.projects {
  position: absolute;
  padding-left: 100vh;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding-right: auto;
}
.contacts {
  position: absolute;
  padding-left: 150vh;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding-right: auto;
}
.title {
  margin-bottom: 6vh;   
  margin-top: 0px;
}

header {
  padding-bottom: 8px;
  padding-top: 9px;
}
}
```

```html
<header>     
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <ul class="title">
          <a class="about" href="#">ABOUT ME</a>
           <a class="skills" href="#">SKILLS</a>
           <a class="projects" href="#">PROJECTS</a>
          <a class="contacts" href="#">CONTACTS</a>
        </ul>
</header>
```

Comment: Please add some comments about your code and how does it answers the question.